# Spring Boot hangs indefinitely when serving JSP content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

The app previously worked on another machine, so the code should all be valid. I'm having difficulties porting it to another machine. Namely, the problem is that when it's time to serve a JSP view, the app hangs indefinitely.

The controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String bookings(BookingFilterRequest bookingFilterRequest,
                           PeriodRequest periodRequest,
                           Model model,
                           BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // Fetch data from database, do things
        return "booking/bookings"; // serve JSP view
    }
```

The code runs fine up until the `return "booking/bookings"` line, which is where it hangs. The JSP view is in the correct folder, otherwise it would give a `not found` error.

I tried installing the same java and gradle versions that the previous server had, with no change.

Version information (default installed versions on new server):

```
openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode)
Gradle 4.4.1
```

Old server had `java 10.0.2` and `gradle 5.0`.

How do I get it to run without hanging?

Update:

If I wait about 10 minutes, then it magically starts working. But restarting the application makes it hang again, until you wait 10 minutes again.

Update2:

If I put console print lines in the JSP file, then they are not printed out. Meaning, the JSP does not get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

Looks like it was a bug in Tomcat. I was finally able to get it working using Jetty. Steps:

1) Use Jetty instead of Tomcat. In build.gradle dependencies section, comment out `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` and `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper` lines and add:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
   exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
compile("org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jsp")
compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
```

2) Build the war file. Jar files didn't work for me, since Jetty didn't find the JSP files when I used jar. If you cant build war files, then make sure you have this in your `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'war'
}
```

It needs to be right after the `buildscript` code block.

Build the war file using

`gradle build war`

It will appear in your `build/libs/` directory.

3) Run the application:

`java -jar application.war`

---

## Extra stuff

Here's my complete `build.gradle` file if it's useful to anyone. I'm aware there are a few unnecessary lines there.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
   id 'war'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'com.project.foo.bar.Application'


bootJar {
    baseName = 'bar'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
      exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")    
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    // persistence
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.3.RELEASE")
    compile("commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.11.Final")
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    // servlets
    compile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1")
    compile("javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1")
    // runtime("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    compile("org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jsp")
    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue as well. It would only happen after going through a certain codepath in one of our servlet filters but I don't know how that caused it.

After some deep dive debugging, I found that the JSP compilation stage was doing...something. I don't know what but the CPU was maxed and the request was hung. This was happening in the tomcat-embed-jasper.jar so yes, Tomcat specific.

Since it was only happening during compilation after the servlet filter I wondered if we could pre-compile them. Turns out yes!

I added the `preCompileJspsAtStartup` bean from this answer and now everything works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651338/397103

(Spring Boot 3, Tomcat 10.1.10, Java 17)